# How do I change the sourcefile of the console.log line in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

When using the Debug Console in Visual Studio Code, each line shows the file that called the function `console.log`. I created a small library called `log.js` that does all the logging. Now the Debug Console is showing only that as source. Is there a way to change this to another file?

[image: Debug Console]
*(see the "log.js" as source in the right of the screenshot)*

### Example

The `log.js` file would look like this:

```
function log(logText) {
  console.log(logText); 
}
module.exports = { log };
```

Another file called `hello-world.js` would call the log function of the `log.js` file:

```
const log = require('./log.js');
log('test');
```

I would like the Debug Console to show "`hello-world.js`" in as a source on the right.

Comment: generate and catch an exception in your `log` function and inspect the call stack and extract the file name